# regex for matching lastName, firstName, middleName

Tags: regex

I have a regex below to find lastName, firstName, middleName with dots, without dots, with spaces, without spaces etc. How to improve my regex, to match all my examples without issues?

```
   [А-Я]+[а-я]*\s+[А-Я]\.*[а-я]*\.*\s*[А-Я]*[а-я]*\.*\,*
```

Issues are highlighting in in https://regex101.com/

```
Просроченные % Жирковой В.М.
Просроч. % Боброва Г. К.
П/отчет Туровой Венеры Мстиславовны
П/отчет Блохин Д. Л. на команд.расх.
П/отчет Соколов Петр Макарович на командир.расходы
П/отчет Силина Ангелина Витальевна
Расчеты с Титовым Е. А.
Проезд Эверстовой Л.В.
Проезд в отпуск Ермакова Венера Якововлевна
ДБП по соглашению с Тетерин ВР
РВПС по просрочке Комаров Н. Ф.
П/отчет Сафоновой Г.И
П/отчет Кривцовой В.И,
П/отчет Румянцевой А.Б
П/отчет Моисеева В А
П/отчет Богданов Р Д на командировочные расходы
Подотчет на командировочные расходыИсаевой Е.Р.
РВПС МАРКОВ ВЯЧЕСЛАВ ВИКТОРОВИЧ № 101 
Перерасход Белокопытов Валерия Станиславовна ДО Алдан
счет накопленных процентов Королева Александра Мартыновна
Задолженность Кулагин А. В., списанная за счет резервов на возможные потери
Задолженность Шаровой Н. М., списанная за счет резервов на возможные потери
Поруч-во Ларионова В
Поруч-во Попов Г.
Залог Князев Серапеон Юрьевич
Залог Тарасов Макар Борисович
Требования по услугам сотовой связи Мегафон к Поляков И. Г.
Задолженность по кредиту Самойлова Т. С. 3330/06П., списанная за счет резервов на возможные потери
Задолженность по кредиту Гришин Пётр Аристархович, списанная за счет резервов на возможные потери
Обеспечение залог транспорта Степановой О.Н. по кред дог №232/08 от 13.08.08 Сазонов Вадим Даниилович
Просроченный кредит Матвиенко Нина Владимировна
Просроченный кредит Горбачев Леонид Григорьевич
По договору купли-продажи акций с Михеев Ю. К.
Резервы на возможные потери по госпошлине Романова Л. Г.
Резервы на возможные потери по госпошлине Денисов П. А.
РВП по задолженности за услуги связи Ситникова ТА.
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output. The majority of the world is not familiar with this type of letters/ words.

Comment: Also, the link does not work.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that for a limited and known set of data, it is probably possible to build a functional Regex, however if the goal is general extensibility to match *any* name, you need to be careful. There's a great post somewhere (I couldn't find the link) highlighting how there are many valid and non-standard name forms that could appear in a data set, and writing a regex to capture all of them can get quite tricky. For example, not everyone has a middle name. Some people have multiple names for a "first name" that may or may not be hyphenated, etc. Just worth keeping in mind.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Whilst I think it's important to tone down the expectations of what can be achieved with regex, it's never going to be able to adequately match names with any accuracy, and I feel the comments on the question have dealt with that; so with that said, I'm always for actually answering the question at hand because we never really know *why* someone might want this (maybe they just want to learn!).</sub>

There are a few things to change with your regex, one of the more interesting you might not know is that the Cyrillic alphabet is not `[А-Яа-я]` but rather [`Ѐ-Яа-џ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode), so you were never going to match names like `Гришин Пётр Аристархович` (since `ё` is outside `[а-я]`).

```
(?<=^|\s)([Ѐ-Я](?:[а-џ]+))((?:(?<=\.|[Ѐ-Я])| )[Ѐ-Я](?:[а-џ]*|\.|(?=[Ѐ-Я]|\s|$))){1,2}(?=\s*(?:$|\r|\n|\s[а-џ]|[^Ѐ-Яа-џ\s.]))
```

[image]

Here you can see the first name in green, middle [if any] in blue, and surname in orange and it does this solely based on these assumptions:

- the first name is a capital letter, followed by lowercase letters, and separated from further names by a single space
- there are one or two names following this first name
- these later names may either take the form of the first name, or be a single capital letter followed by a space, a period, or another name
- the end of the name is only recognisable at the end of a line, some other word (something beginning with a lowercase letter), or a non-word non-whitespace character

But outside of a toy for learning, or perhaps a highlighting *aid* for human reading, it would never be perfect, for that you would need actual language parsers; something that understands not names, but all the other words and the syntax between them.